# Django smart select many to many field filter_horizontal/filter_vertical does not allow chaining

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, chaining, django-smart-selects

Hi I am doing a project in Django 1.10. For this project I am using django-smart-select for chaining input in the admin panel.
It works fine. But for many to many fields chaining if I use filter_horizontal/filter_vertical then the chaining does not work any more.
There was no solution in there github page. 
How can i solve this problem? Is there another app like this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved it in this fork from the library: https://github.com/jorgecorrea/django-smart-selects
As you can see in my README version, this is the way to use in horizontal mode with mi fork:
models.py

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedManyToManyField

class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Writer(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        publications = models.ManyToManyField('Publication', 
                                              blank=True,
                                              null=True)

class Book(models.Model):
        publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication)
        writer = ChainedManyToManyField(
            Writer,
            horizontal=True,
            verbose_name='writer',
            chained_field="publication",
            chained_model_field="publications",
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

with this little change you can use django horizontal mode view, but do not add the field to admin filter_horizontal
this change is not needed:
admin.py

```
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('writer',)
   # don't do that because you will be changing the widget.
```